# Trying to use JS object to populate Components but get "Functions not valid as React child"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm quite new to React so forgive me if this is a simple issue.

I'm trying to use a JavaScript Object:

```
const gameCardData = {
  "university": {
    "elemental-wars": {
      "imgAlt": "Elemental Wars Start Screen",
      "imgPath": "../img/games/ElementalWars.png",
      "cardHeader": "Elemental Wars",
      "cardShortText": "A tactical game about using your units and spells to outsmart an opposing mage",
      "cardPlatforms": "Windows",
      "cardDate": "2018",
      "cardEngine": "Unity",
      "cardRoles": "Lead Programmer"
    }
  }
};

export default gameCardData;
```

to populate some components. The idea is that for every child in "university" I'll have a card with some information on it. But when I try and call this function:

```
getGameCards = category => () => {
    let data = gameCardData[category];
    return(
        <div>
            <ComplexCard
                imgAlt="Image alt"//{game.imgAlt}
                imgPath={require("../img/games/ElementalWars.png")}//game.imgPath)}
                cardHeader="Elemental Wars"//{game.cardHeader}
                cardShortText="A tactical game about using your units and spells to outsmart an opposing mage"//{game.cardShortText}
                cardPlatforms="Windows"//{game.cardPlatforms}
                cardEngine="Unity"//{game.cardEngine}
                cardRoles="Lead Programmer"//{game.cardRoles}
                cardDate="2018"//{game.cardDate}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

I get this warning and nothing shows up on screen:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I call the function like this:

```
class ComplexCardGrid extends Component {
...
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.getGameCards("university")}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And before you say anything, yes, I know the `getGameCards` doesn't make use of the data I'm providing, yet, but this was just to get a working example before I use a for loop to create all of the cards based on the data provided.

But how would I get rid of this warning? I imagine it's something fundamental about React I don't understand because the solution to it doesn't seem to be the same when I look up the question on Google.

Comment: remove `() =>` from `getGameCard` declaration. currently you have declared function that returns function that returns elements so you either need to call it like `this.getGameCard("universe")()` or remove extra `() =>` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two arrow (=>) in your code

```
getGameCards = category => () => {
```

that means you have two function that the first one is waiting for return of the second one. that you must call it like this:

```
getGameCards()()
```

so you should just remove one of them:

```
getGameCards = category => {
```

Comment: Thank you, that explanation also educates.

Answer (score 2):

change the following..

```
getGameCards = category => () => {
```

to:

```
getGameCards = category => {
```